# Reparameterized geodesics - proof

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I was reading the proof for the lemma that states that a certain curve c is a reparameterized geodesic if and only if it satisfies $\frac{D\dot{c}}{dt}=f(t)\dot{c}$. The starting point was defining curve c as $c(t):=\gamma (s(t))$ and so $\dot{c}(t)=\dot{\gamma}(s(t))\frac{ds}{dt}(t)$.
At certain point we get:
$$\nabla_{\dot{c}}\dot{c}=\nabla_{\dot{c}}(\frac{ds}{dt}\dot{\gamma})=(\frac{d^2s}{dt^2})\dot{\gamma}+(\frac{ds}{dt})\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}\frac{ds}{dt}}\dot{\gamma}$$
I understand this comes from applying the properties of the affine connection but I don't get how the term $(\frac{d^2s}{dt^2})\dot{\gamma}$ shows up.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what reference are you using? Do Carmo?

Comment: In this case no, I'm using Introduction to Riemannian Geometry by José Natário.

Comment: I also got a factor $\frac{ds}{dt}$, but in the book it is written as mentioned above.

Comment: It should be $\nabla_{\dot{c}}\dot{c}$ since we're checking it's a geodesic right? $\frac{D\dot{c}}{dt}$.